# How to increase performance of a doubly linked list in java?

Tags: java, performance, doubly-linked-list

So I have an assignment that asks me to modify a method that traverses a doubly linked list. I got it to work, but our prof. set it up in a way that you can only receive full marks if the methods work faster than the one he provided. The list is 10000 elements.

This is how the original traverses the list:

```
private Node getNodeAt(int givenPosition)
{
    Node currentNode = firstNode;

    for(int counter = 1; counter < givenPosition; counter++)
    {
        currentNode = currentNode.next;
    }

    return currentNode;
```

this takes about 1331 milliseconds.
This is one way we were told to traverse the list:

```
    private Node getNodeAt2(int givenPosition)
    {
     Node currentNode = firstNode;
     middleNode = firstNode;
     boolean nearFront = givenPosition <= (numberOfEntries / 4);
     boolean nearFrontMid = (givenPosition < (numberOfEntries / 2)) && (givenPosition > (numberOfEntries / 4));
     boolean nearBackMid = (givenPosition >= (numberOfEntries / 2)) && (givenPosition < ((3*numberOfEntries) / 4));
     boolean nearLast = (givenPosition >= ((3*numberOfEntries) / 4));

     middlePosition = numberOfEntries / 2;

     for(int counter = 1; counter < middlePosition; counter++)
     {
      middleNode = middleNode.next;
     }

     if(nearFront){
       currentNode = firstNode;
     for(int counter = 1; counter < givenPosition; counter++)
        {
         currentNode = currentNode.next;
        }
     }
     if(nearFrontMid){
       currentNode = middleNode;
       for(int counter = 1; counter <= (middlePosition - givenPosition) ; counter++)
         {
         currentNode = currentNode.previous;
         }

     }
     if(nearBackMid){
       currentNode = middleNode;
       for(int counter = 1; counter <= (givenPosition - middlePosition); counter++)
        {
        currentNode = currentNode.next;
        }

     }
     if (nearLast){
       currentNode = lastNode;
       for(int counter = 1; counter <= (numberOfEntries - givenPosition); counter++)
     {
      currentNode = currentNode.previous;
     }
  }

    return currentNode;
```

This one takes about 800 milliseconds, and even though it is faster, he expects it to take a quarter of the time the first method takes. Is that possible?

Comment: can you explain how that second method is faster than the first one?

Comment: The first thing that stands out to me is your `if` statements don't have any else's separating them, so if more than one are true, then more than one run.  The point of them seems to be the find the nearest approximate node and only traverse from there, so I'd think you want to only enter one block at the most.

Comment: @Brandon: Seeing how the conditions (`nearXXX`) are constructed, only one of them will run. However, I fail to see how this is faster than just the simple iteration, unless the cut points are cached somewhere.

Comment: @thilo Its faster because depending on the given position it starts at different places on the list.It starts from the middle and goes forward or backward depending on if the given position is closer to which end of the list. It'll start from the end if the given position is very large.

Comment: @Devin_Kinh But it iterates to the half-way point in order to find the middle node.  Then scans from the middle-point forward or backward.  It's like cutting the time in half and then doubling it.  I don't see why it would be significantly faster.

Comment: This would probably be a better question for Code Review than for Stack Overflow.

Comment: @Brandon Ah that might be away I could make it faster

Comment: @keshlam sorry I'm new I don't know protocol haha

Comment: @Devin_Kinh Hint: You are on the right track.  Is there anything you can change outside of this method that might avoid the need to search for the mid-point in this method?

Comment: @Brandon we were told specifically to use a middleNode and to find that middleNode using an integer middle position so i don't think i can. I suppose I put the search for the middle node outside the method so its not searching everytime its called. You think that would be better?

Comment: @Brandon it worked! the first one took about 900 milliseconds and the one I made took about 200 milliseconds. Thanks everyone!

Comment: I highly recommend using a microbenchmark framework like Caliper (from Google, maker of fast things) to do A/B algorithm comparisons. JIT can radically affect results. See https://code.google.com/p/caliper/wiki/JavaMicrobenchmarks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some Thoughts:

1)
In the second solution the middleNode is always searched, but it isn't needed every time (especially at the if-parts nearfront and nearlast ). It will be faster if the middleNode is just determined when it's needed.

2) The iteration is faster because the method knows where the middleNode is. Maybe "quaterNodes" help.

3) Sometimes recurrsive iterations are faster than a loop. Instead of looping call a method which is 1 step closer to the needed position.
With 10000-elements there won't be any limit.